# Safe to remove Evolution?

Tags: 11.10, evolution, thunderbird

I automatically upgraded from 11.04 to 11.10 but never used Evolution. Now that Thunderbird is the default mail client; Can I remove Evolution completely, safely? Did it come pre-installed on 11.10? I remember that if I pressed the Time on the top bar Evolution Set Up Assistant opened up. Is there a substitute for this?

Any suggestion is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, remove it. I have removed both Evolution (not pre-installed on 11.10) *and* Thunderbird with no problems.

Answer (score 0):

I have been using 11.10 since alpha 2. The mail icon definitely loads Thunderbird. I have just searched the dash for Evolution and I got an icon for Evolution Mail and Calendar for download. If I click on it the Ubuntu software Centre opens ready to down load Evolution.

So, Evolution is not pre-installed on 11.10 but it is easy to get for those who do not want to use Thnderbird.

Whenever I click time, whether in 11.04 or 11.10, I get the time/date utility. Are you sure you are not clicking the envelope icon?

Regards.

Comment: Thanks, what I meant was when I press any day of the calendar after pressing the Date/Time on the top bar. That's what activated the "Evolution Set Up Assistant". Again thanks for the help.